# Job applications and visible health condition

Tags: job-search, health

I would like to ask what the best way to proceed could be when submitting job applications given my health conditions: currently a postdoc in physics, I am affected by essential tremor (ET), the most common movement disorder, that in my case amounts to shaky hands and arms and probably affects voice also. The problem is greatly amplified by stress and nerves, while when I am calm basically I look completely normal. You can easily imagine how this caused me to battle with non-motor psychological consequences revolving around the anxiety and embarrassment that such a problem causes.

Given that I cannot avoid appearing scared during a job interview due to the aforementioned health problem even though I am as nervous as anyone else, and in view of the bias against lack of confidence and communication skills, that are inevitably damaged by ET, I feel like no one could take my application seriously without knowing in advance what I am battling with and trying to filter out the appearance to focus on the substance of what I say only.

Should I disclose the problem prior to applying to a position? Are there inclusive policies in universities or related scientific facilities that give me a fair chance of getting a job? I feel a bit dizzy thinking about my future, considering also that my tremors can only get worse with time (I am only 27).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are already a postdoc, how did you deal with this problem the first time around? What makes you think it would be different next time? Anyway, in many countries there are laws which make it illegal to discriminate against people with disabilities when hiring. In the UK, for example, the vast majority of employers will ask you to voluntarily disclose information about your disability when applying. I suppose this is partly for statistical purposes and partly so they can make any necessary accommodations during interviews.

Comment: Is your condition and/or ET a recognized disability?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! At the moment the problem is quite manageable, especially after I started to take medication to control it, so it definitely isn't a significant source of disability now, far from it. My job interview took place online during covid, so that helped release some stress, but I have also done things in person.

Comment: Currently, my main concern is a more subtle one, namely that an unaware recruiter would misunderstand an occurence of shaky hands and/or voice during a stressful activity such as a job interview and as a result discard my application because he doesn't know I can't help but look way more anxious and terrified than I actually am. In summary, it is luckily far from being that bad to be called a disability, but at the same time it impairs my ability to behave perfectly normally under stressful circumstances (trust me, losing control of your hands under stress is anything but pleasant).

Comment: You might consider asking this question on Workplace.SE to get a broader perspective on the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, I think you should directly address the issue at the interview stage (not at the application stage) in a casual way. I say this because I have a bit of a condition where my neck becomes very red and blotchy when I have too much adrenaline/am stressed. This has concerned interviewers in the past because they think I am having some sort of allergic reaction. I bring it up now because it is much more awkward when they bring it up first.

To address the issue casually, I would say (or perhaps pre-email) something like, "I want to give you a heads up that I have an essential tremor condition. It is usually not noticeable but it can act up when I get a burst of adrenaline - which sometimes happens in exciting situations like an interview. You'll notice my arms shaking, but its not anything to worry about." Here, you will notice that I talk about adrenaline and excitement, not stress or nervousness. I have found this phrasing has a more positive connotation.

Answer (score 2):

At least in Europe, many universities start asking about health conditions already during the submission stage. I understand that this is more targeted towards more impactful disabilities which may require special care or fall under a legally protected class, but I would probably bring it up there already.

Additionally, what I would do is email the chair shortly before the interviews and inform them (in a very curt manner) about your condition. Your goal is not to make this seem like a big deal (it isn't), but to clarify upfront (before a narrative can form in the heads of people). The tone I would go for is similar to how I would inform them about allergies in preparation of joint lunches / dinner - it's an FYI first and foremost, not an apology.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is limited harm in being upfront. Ultimately this is something that you have to deal with daily and you can choose how open to be about it. If letting people know why your hands shake makes you feel more secure or confident, then go for it. Depending on where you are, you probably have some legal protections either way. As long as you have documentation supporting your diagnosis, it should not negatively impact your job search. More importantly, you presumably want to work in an environment that is supportive and accommodates you willingly. Being upfront prevents any misinterpretation or bias (which you are worried about) and has the added benefit of weeding out any departments/companies that would not accommodate you (or do so begrudgingly). Although it's worth mentioning that since you don't seem to need any special accommodations, I don't see most employers caring.

In the real world, you may not have the luxury of being picky about where you work. At least in the US, you don't really need a reason *not* to hire a candidate. Certainly there are companies that will try to avoid hiring someone who will require accommodations (despite the fact that it is unethical/illegal). Only you know your specific situation. This *should* not impact your job prospects but it *might*. Whether or not it would affect you more than appearing overly nervous is impossible to guess.

With that in mind, before doing anything or worrying too much, maybe you should consider having a trusted 3rd party (maybe your physician?) assess how severe your tremor is to the untrained eye. It's possible that a non-medical person might not even be aware of it during an interview. You could avoid the issue altogether if this is the case.